# targeting a column value in a Multicolumns class in a django cms for responsive design

Tags: css, django, content-management-system

I am working on making the columns created by the user to be responsive. The cms can generate multicolumn from 1 to 10 and every column value can be created with a set width that ranges from 10%, 25%, 33%, 50%, 66%, 75%, 100%. 
 [CMS interface][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYZrU.png

I am making a responsive image grid that needs to target all possible column size that a user can make and flex it to a % based on the width size of the column (width:10% than flex:10%):
 [how the cms code columns is generated][2][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVWvP.png
So here is an example of how I have targeted the multicolumn class:

```
.row.cms-extra-style div[class^= "multicolumn"]/*.multicolumn10*/{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;
    align-items: center;
}
.multicolumn10>.column{
    flex: 10%;
    max-width: 10%;
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding: 0 4px;
}
```

However, that says all .multicolumn10 will be 10% which is not the case. The user can make multicolumn10 @ 10%, 25%, 33%, 50%, 66%, 75%, 100%. but the CMS makes it by adding an embedded "style width: %"; so is there a way I can say if this column has a width of % flex: same% in CSS?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the image and code inline, not as links

Comment: I don't have 10 points so I can't do it.